# Анализ сайта: извлечние статей

Tags: анализ

Разработать систему, на вход которой будет поступать адрес сайта, а на выходе должны получиться статьи, несущие смысловую информацию.

Т. е. необходимо проанализировать сайт, найти все статьи, убрать из них все лишнее и сохранить их.

С тем как вытащить статью из страницы проблем нет. В интернете куча как статей, так и готовых решений. Главная проблема в анализе сайта. Например как найти раздел со статьями или отделить панель навигации по страницам от простого меню и т. д.

Comment: Вы хотите парсить любой сайт?

Answer (score 1):

Отличить заголовок статьи от меню - возможно вообще дело безнадёжное, а вот содержимое статьи отличается наличием большого числа полных предложений, содержащих глаголы, прилагательные и существительные, знаки припинания. Так что можно сформулировать такое требование: в искомом тексте должно быть *несколько* предложений, разделённых точками, и содержащих не менее одного глагола, одного существительного и одного прилагательного. Определить часть речи для русского языка можно по окончанию.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно новостные сайты предоставляют ленту новостей, описание статей в формате rss. При этом иногда скрывая подобное от пользователя и ориентируясь на инф рессурсы типа ukr.net Лучше идти по пути минимального сопротивления и использовать подобное в своих целях.